# How to compare two products in two different pages

Tags: java, spring, struts2

How to compare two products which are in different pages.
i.e.I wil check one checkbox in one jsp page and other checkbox in  another page.The problem is if i navigated to other page checkbox checked in first page is not working.Please help me using java and jsp.

Comment: You want to compare values of two check boxes?

Comment: @poorna1221 what you mean by checkboxes not working?

Answer (score 2):

When you say "checkbox checked in first page is not working", i assume you mean that the checkbox becomes unchecked.
You need to store your data in session score for it to be available across JSP pages ( you could forward data from one page to another, but storing in session score is the simpler thing to do).

So when you move from one jsp to another, you could do something like

```
List productList = new ArrayList();
productList.add("xyzProdName");
session.setAttribute("ProductList", productList);
```

the attribute productList here represents a list which stores product names. You will have embbed such java code in your JSP. I suggest look up tag implementation instead of embedding code directly.

Once your product names are in session you can fetch their data and compare.

Make sure to empty the session if the user deselects products.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to save the state of that `checkbox` internally, and do the comparison when you need to.